# Javascript program to automate task

Tags: javascript

I am trying to automate a tedious task we do at my current job. We have a website we use to process customer orders and every day, we have to print out papers and force orders over so they can be processed.

I had done it before using Python and the Selenium Webdriver but that stopped working because they upgraded the PCs (and I would like to try utilizing Javascript instead now since it's built into the web browsers (was previously running the script off a flash drive that had python installed on it). I've figured out most of the basic stuff, but I'm having trouble finding answers to how this can be done.

I need to be able to run the script easily (not just me but my coworkers as well when I'm not there and they're all not very knowledgeable in this stuff).

Is it possible to actually write a Javascript script that can be run and automate this task? The website does require us to login. With Pytbon, I used a GUI form where the user would type in their username, password, and a day of the week and it would take those values and just login and navigate the pages, "clicking" everything for us and printing. Would prefer to be able to do it in Internet Explorer because that's what the website we use is optimized for (chrome has weird side effects when the paperwork is printed).

Thanks to anyone who can give me some advice, suggestions, or even links to other resources that could help.

Comment: Any chance you could edit your question to include the Python code? It would be helpful to see it.

Comment: Optimized for Internet Explorer? R.I.P. What kind of side effects are you getting? Maybe solving that problem would make your life easier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Node.js and the selenium webdriver module with promises get this done.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-webdriver

You could create this in a way where all you have to do is run the command and the program will be automated with feedback.

Comment: If you run this on a server you could also make it recurring

Comment: Yeah, the Selenium webdriver is how I did the Python one.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a browser window open you can simply do something like this:

```
setInterval(() => {
 // automation logic goes here

// get current date


// get DOM elements


// simulate inputs and clicks

}, 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
```

This will run once every 24h.